# PHP error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file... on line 170

Tags: php, html

I am learning PHP and using it with my knowledge of SQL and HTML to make a login system. However when I reached the point where I wanted to test and see the input validation I put in for the HTML input fields I got the error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/neil2/public_html/login/register2.php on line 170

I researched the problem and have found out that this happens mostly because of missing a bracket or semicolon in the PHP script however I have looked and cannot seem to find it. I tried putting the code into Notepad++ to show me the beginning and end of the if statements and functions however there doesn't appear to be any missing and I think that it maybe something else. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: The code is still being built so they maybe more errors in there but I was not able to get rid of them before posting here due to this error.

```
<?php
$username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
$password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
$password2 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['retypepassword']);
$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
$secquest = htmlspecialchars($_POST['secrquest']);
$secans = hash("sha512", $_POST['secrans'], "true");

include_once("php/db_connect.php");
session_start();

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{
    if (empty($username)) 
    {
        $userempty = "Please enter a username!";
    } else {
        checkdata ($username);
    }
    if (empty($name)) 
    {
        $nameempty = "Please enter your name!";
    } else {
    checkdata ($name);
    }
    if (empty($email))
    {
        $emailempty = "Please enter your email address!";
    } else {
        checkdata ($email);
    }
    if (empty($secquest)) 
    {
        $secqempty = "Please enter a security question!";
    } else {
    checkdata ($secquest);
    }
}

$usernamecomplete;
$usernameerror;
Usernamestuff ($dbconnect, $username, $usernamecomplete, $usernameerror);

$passwordcomplete;
$passworderror;
Passwordstuff ($password, $password2, $secpass, $passwordcomplete, $passworderror);

function checkdata ($data)
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
return $data;
}

function Usernamestuff ($dbconnect, $user, $uc, $ue)
{
$usercheck = "SELECT username FROM members WHERE username='$user'";
$userq = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $usercheck);
$numuser = mysqli_num_rows($userq);
    if (numuser == 0) 
    {
        $uc = TRUE;
        $ue = 0;
    } else {
        $uc = FALSE;
        $ue = 1;
    }
}

function Passwordstuff ($pw, $pw2, $scpw, $pc, $pe)
{
$same = strcmp($pw, $pw2);
if ($same == 0)
{
    $scpw = hash("sha256", $pw, "true");
    $pc = TRUE;
    $pe = 0;
} else {
    $pc = FALSE;
    $pe = 1;
}

function Emailstuff ($dbconnect, $email, $ec, $er)
{
    $emailcheck = "SELECT email FROM members WHERE email='$email'";
    $emailq = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $emailcheck);
    $numemail = mysqli_num_rows($emailq);
    if ($numemail == 0)
    {
        $ec = TRUE;
        $er = 0;
    } else {
        $ec = FALSE;
        $er = 1;
    }
}

function Insertmember ($dbconnect, $user, $scpw, $name, $email, $scqu, $scan)
{
$insertinfo = "INSERT INTO members VALUES (NULL, '$username', '$scpw', '$name', '$email', '$scqu', '$scan', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); ";
mysqli_query($dbconnect, $insertinfo);
}
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Register</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #Username {
            width: 141px;
        }
        #Password {
            width: 141px;
        }
        #Name {
            width: 141px;
        }
        #Email {
            width: 141px;
        }
        #SecurityQuestion {
            width: 260px;
        }
        #SecurityAnswer {
            width: 141px;
        }
        #regiser {
            width: 89px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="height: 221px">
    <form id="register_form" method="POST" action="register2.php">
    <div>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Register</legend>
        * Required Field
        <input id="Username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" /> 
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $userempty; ?></span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <input id="Password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" /> *
        <br />
        <br />
        <input id="Password" type="password" name="retypepassword" placeholder="Retype Password" /> *
        <br />
        <br />
        <input id="Name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name" /> *
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameempty; ?></span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <input id="Email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" /> 
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailempty; ?></span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <input id="SecurityQuestion" type="text" name="secrquest" value="Mothers Maiden name?" /> *
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $secqempty; ?></span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <input id="SecurityAnswer" type="text" name="secrans" placeholder="Security Question Answer" /> *
        <br />
        <br />
        <input id="register" type="submit" value="Register" />
        <br />
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function Passwordstuff ($pw, $pw2, $scpw, $pc, $pe)
{
$same = strcmp($pw, $pw2);
if ($same == 0)
{
    $scpw = hash("sha256", $pw, "true");
    $pc = TRUE;
    $pe = 0;
} else {
    $pc = FALSE;
    $pe = 1;
}
```

Missing closing `}`

In case you are interested, have a look at a popular `php` style guide to help provide a "standard" way to format your code. It may prove to save you time in the long run.

http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/

Comment: Thank you very much. Must have slipped by.